# Why isn't my EditorTemplate firing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editortemplates

Here's the item from the View

```
 @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.BirthDate)
```

Here's the code from the EditorTemplate (simplified)

```
@ModelType Date?
<span>
    @Html.TextBox("", Model)
</span>
```

but the output doesn't have the span tags.

The datatype of the `model.BirthDate` is `Date?`

The folder structure is

- Views

  - Shared

    - EditorTemplates

      - Date.vbhtml

#### EDIT

Ok, so after some digging, I found that if I add `<UIHint("Date")>` to my BuddyClass, then the template works.

So my "new" question would be... why wouldn't it pick this up by default?

Comment: oh, and before you comment on why I'm using `@ModelType` instead of `@Model`... it's because its the difference between VB and C# :)

Comment: If your DateOfBirth property is a DateTime the your template should be called DataTIme.vbhtml

Comment: the BirthDate property is `Date?` because a) I don't really care the time of birth, and b) I'm not requiring the user to tell me their birthdate at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. @Brad Wilson answered my question over at the [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/1626845/4185113.aspx).

> The default template name is based on the CLR type name, in this case DateTime. "Date" is a shortcut name in VB, not the real type name (much like "int" in C# is really a shortcut for CLR's "Int32")

Now I get it. Thanks @Brad